# The difference between a bridge and an interface

Tags: design-patterns

As far as I understand, the purpose of a Bridge pattern is, quoting from Wikipedia, "to decouple an abstraction from its implementation". Well isn't that exactly what an interface does. By deciding on an interface and forcing a class to use that interface, any other class can interact with this one without the need for any knowledge about the internal workings.

So is an interface equivalent to a Bridge?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interface just means "public API" of something: That is the contract against which you write software. Java uses the keyword `interface` to define classes without code that contain such contracts.

The bridge pattern is a design pattern. It stands for decoupling. You could say Java interfaces are one way to implement this pattern.

Note that bridges usually expose the full API while Java interfaces can expose only part of the API. Example: You have a class `Foo` with two methods: `bar()` and `baz()`.

A bridge is anything which has the same public API as `Foo` and which can be used in any place where `Foo` can be used.

With interfaces, you can have two. One contains `bar()` and the other `baz()`. Any class which implements both is a valid implementation for `Foo` but you can also have classes which implement only one of them.

Answer (score 1):

"Interface" generally refers to what is public in a class. As far as I understand it, in the Bridge pattern you actually have separate classes for the interface and the implementation.

Comment: In Java (any other languages that allow the definition of interfaces), it's customary to separate the interface from the classes that implement them. Though I agree with public members in a class being an "interface", I don't think that's what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Ok. Then I'd say that the interface itself represents one layer of abstraction, while with the bridge pattern you actually have two layers of abstraction, which becomes evident e.g. in the diagram of the corresponding wikipedia entry.

Answer (score 0):

An interface is a contract that an implementation must obey.  A bridge uses interfaces to achieve its goal which is to separate some concrete implementation from the client interface it agrees with so that the client needs little (or rather no) knowledge of the details of how the service it is using works.

Answer (score -1):

Are you talking about an `Interface` (as in the Language construct present in many Java-like languages)? Or just "interface" as in "the things that a type exposes to its clients"?

There's a big difference, one is a non-universal language specific detail (and for those language which implement an `Interface` type your statement functions similarly to a Bridge), and the other is universal to all OO languages (that I know of).  For the "interface" of a class, then no your statement is not true.